# How to use OpenCV 3 with OpenFrameworks?

Tags: openframeworks

I'm trying to use OpenCV version 3 with OpenFrameworks. I don't see any example code of how to use it. Can anyone suggest how to combine these two?

Comment: I highly recommend [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) mostly because it enables to work directly with CV (much cleaner in my opinion). I don't know if it would be easy to make it work with OpenCV 3.

Comment: You can also have a look on the ofx [addons](http://www.ofxaddons.com/) to see if there is anything matching your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle McDonald's [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) is the easiest way to use modern OpenCV in OpenFramworks.

Keep in mind though that the default opencv libraries for the OpenFrameworks addons may be older. 
However you should be able to update them.

If you have OpenCV 3.0, you can build the library for your machine for the current operating system and the architecture you use in OpenFrameworks (32bit probably).

Once you have the OpenCV 3.0 built libraries you should be able to add them to your ofxCv,ofxOpenCv project initially to make sure they link correctly and aftwards update the addons with these libraries.

This may not be super straight forward if you are a beginner so before you do that, make sure that the opencv features you are planning to use for your project aren't already available in the version of opencv that ships with the openframworks addons.